# Restrictions of Coinbase API

Tags: coinbase-api

Just wondering if there are any restrictions to the API such as our product has multiple clients and wondering if the integration option is only allowed for 1:coinbase integrations

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information in your question, but I will point out general information: each request through the REST API requires the key,secret,passphrase for a given account. I see no reason why multiple accounts could not be handled as long as you use the right credentials for each request.